# Regular expression: why a?? pattern matches empty string "" from any string including "a" itself?

Tags: regex

From this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) I learned about "Regular Expressions - Quantifiers", and based on this [test code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html) used in this tutorial.

```
Enter your regex: a??
Enter input string to search: a
I found the text "" starting at index 0 and ending at index 0.
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1.
```

And

```
Enter your regex: a??
Enter input string to search: aaa
I found the text "" starting at index 0 and ending at index 0.
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "" starting at index 2 and ending at index 2.
I found the text "" starting at index 3 and ending at index 3.
```

Also

```
Enter your regex: a??
Enter input string to search: cab
I found the text "" starting at index 0 and ending at index 0.
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "" starting at index 2 and ending at index 2.
I found the text "" starting at index 3 and ending at index 3.
```

**Why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`??` is a quantifier, so it says how many times the quantified term should be matched, 0 or 1 times, **preferably 0**. `??` on its own doesn't *match* anything, it just decorates another expression, saying how many times that expression is to be matched in the tested string.

**Iff** the rest of the expression doesn't match with a [*lazy*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `0 times` partial match, it will try again with `1 time` partial match.

It's true that if the whole regular expression consists of just a lazy optional match of some term, it will *always* match empty positions inside the tested string. So this kind of quantifier is only useful when there are other terms around it. For example, the expression `ba??d` will first try to match `bd` and then `bad`.

Still, why does the regular expression match once for every character in the string (plus one at the end)? Well, an empty match is a valid regular expression. For example, searching for `^` or `$` (the start, respectively end of the string) will yield a match, albeit empty. The same for this "useless" expression, every position inside the tested string is a valid match for the expression that doesn't impose any constraints on the match.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are doing the `?` operator LAZY with `?` so it will match as less as possible.

You are trying to match an `a` 0 or 1 times, but you are telling the regex engine to match as less as possible so it will match 0 times and it matches that as many characteres are in the string (+1).

Comment: Is there actually _any_ case where `??` matches anything?

Comment: Actually I read it yesterday and I don't think it would match. It's just a general quantifier for the quantifiers themselves to make them lazy.